# generate rand(9) using rand(3)

Tags: random, probability

You have a function rand(3) which generates random integers from 1 to 3. Using this function, construct another function rand(9) which generates random integers from 1 to 9.

Comment: Is this the title of a question from your university book?

Comment: `rand(3) + rand(3) + rand(3)`?

Comment: @Shubham How would that generate a result of 1?

Comment: @Shubham: `rand(3)` generates integers in the `[1,3]` interval so adding three of them would give you integers in `[3,9]`, rather than `[1,9]`.

Comment: Ah, Just missed it. These are one of those problems which are seemingly easy but much if you dissect it.

Comment: @Shubham Even if the you’d want to construct a rand(9) generator which generates numbers in [0,9] by using rand(3) generators which generate numbers in [0,3], your approach would not work. The results would be biased. There would be a significantly higher probability of generating 4 or 5 than 0 or 9.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using rand(3) twice, one can generate 3^2 pairs of integers, i.e. (1,1), (1,2), ..., (3,3). Assigning each pair to one of the values [1,9] (e.g. (1,1) to 1, (1,2) to 2 etc.) will give you rand(9). Symbolically: rand(9):=(rand(3),rand(3)).

Comment: This is true, but using base-3 decomposition, as suggested by Amber, is a more complete answer.

Answer (score 21):

Here's a simple solution:

```
rand(3) + 3*(rand(3) - 1)
```

The reason why you would want to do it like this is that it provides an even distribution over all of the possible values from 1 to 9.

Some people might be tempted to just do `rand(3) * rand(3)`, but that doesn't actually generate some numbers - 7, for instance. It also unevenly distributes the numbers it *does* generate.

Similarly, some people might do `rand(3) + rand(3) + rand(3)`, but this also doesn't generate all of the numbers (it'll never generate 1 or 2), and generates other numbers with disproportionate frequency (5 is generated much more often than 9).

Comment: Do you have a proof that your solution is evenly distributed?

Comment: @Dani It divides the output space up into 3 equally-sized blocks (that's what the latter half does), and then equally picks one of the elements out of one of those blocks (that's what the former half does). Each block has a 1/3 chance of being chosen, and each item in each block has a 1/3 chance of being chosen, thus each item overall has a 1/9 chance of being chosen.